# How to deskew a fisheye panorama using css3?

Tags: javascript, css, 3d

I feel that it has come time to convert my flash panoramas to js/html5/css3. I've seen some elegant solutions using separate flat images, but mine are all fisheye...

My intuition tells me that it's doable using -webkit-transform: matrix3d but I'm not quite hitting it.

Any ideas if this can really be done in css3?

Thanksya kindly.

Comment: can you show us an example of what do you want to do?

Comment: Essentially, I have a panorama flattened as a fisheye image (I believe that that's what it's called when it's warped to be squashed at the bottom and stretched at the top) and I'd like to de-skew the image using css3 to be a 360deg panorama surrounding the viewpoint of the visitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done, but you better know your mathematics. Note that you are not using CSS3 but rather a proprietary extension, this will only work in webkit browsers. You'll probably be better off using a Canvas element for the job, not only is it supported by more browsers, it also gives you far greater freedom to do whatever transformation you desire.

Edit:
Well then, cut your image into a number of thin vertical slices, each slice should be scaled by approx 1/cos([angle off centre]), and skewed to account for the angle being different at the right and the left side of the slice. This way you should end up with an "inverse fisheye" shape where the top and the bottom of the image is concave, you might want to cut it to a square.

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually only interested in webkit for now. =)

Comment: Well, there's -moz-transform too https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/-moz-transform and it'll likely be standardized eventually: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/#transform-property .

Comment: Just because it will be standardized doesn't mean everyone will implement it in the same, or even pay attention *cough*IE*cough*

Answer (score 1):

I discovered [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js).

It looks promising.

Comment: How exactly to do it? Some specific functions and components to look for?