# Panorama viewer for website

Tags: html, panoramas

Is there a panorama viewer for a website which is not Flash/Silverlight/Plugin base? I have the image which is exactly 360, but I don't want the viewer to need flash or any other plugin.

Comment: Define "Panorama viewer". What would it have to be able to do? Click-and-Drag? Zooming?

Comment: I just started working on something like that. And posted a question relating... =) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534028/how-to-deskew-a-fisheye-panorama-using-css3 I'll certainly follow this question so see if there are available solutions.

Comment: well the very basic would be just to scroll left and right and to zoom in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should search some in these:

http://www.all-in-one.ee/~dersch/

http://wiki.panotools.org/Panorama_Viewers

https://github.com/leandigo/leanorama

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 4):

If you can afford not having to worry about IE then WebGL based viewers should be the "future proof" solution. Here are a couple of pointers:

- http://www.mpetroff.net/archives/2012/05/28/introducing-pannellum/
- http://www.clicktorelease.com/code/street/
- http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_panorama_equirectangular.html
- http://www.lizardq.com/posts/experimental-webgl-panorama-viewer/

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of HTML5 (Javascript based) panorama viewers:

KRpano - http://krpano.com/

Pannellum - (github.com/mpetroff/pannellum)

JQuery Panorama Viewer - (github.com/peachananr/panorama_viewer)

I've been working on a javascript library [Panolens](https://github.com/pchen66/panolens.js) as well, which is quite similar to above solutions but with much less procedures and support of 3D creation (built on top of Three.JS). Hope it helps anyone!

Comment: Just had a look at Panolens, have to say I'm very impressed :-)  Great work.